# Why do these .NET 7 JWT Authentication settings fail validating my bearer token / JWT token?

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, bearer-token

I'm trying to determine why these .NET 7 JWT Authentication settings fail .. while the next settings below it, pass.

#### Failing settings

```
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = "some-issuer",
            ValidAudience = applicationOptions.Authentication.Audience
        };
    });

....

var app = builder.Build();
app
    .UseAuthentication()
    .UseAuthorization();
```

Error message:

- Header Key: `WWW-Authenticate`
- Header Value: `Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"`

#### Working / Passing settings

```
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        x.Authority = "some-issuer";
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = "some-issuer",
            ValidAudience = applicationOptions.Authentication.Audience
        };
    });

....

var app = builder.Build();
app
    .UseAuthentication()
    .UseAuthorization();
```

side note: ignore that i've hardcoded the string values - just making it clear for this example.

So in the 2nd code segment, I've included `x.Authority = "some-issuer";`

*I thought* that `ValidIssuer = "some-issuer"` is the exact equiv to `x.Authority` ??

lastly, if I have `x.Authority` and then omit `ValidIssuer = ..` then it *also works*.

Can someone please explain/clarify?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core - AddJwtBearer - Authority URL, how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613311/asp-net-core-addjwtbearer-authority-url-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Hi @sa-es-ir and thank you for your comments. I don't think that other SO question, answers my question though? I'm trying to find out why the 2nd code works when an `x.Authority` is provided and that other SO question/answer doesn't explain this? Or maybe I just can't read it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what [@Ajay Managaon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21362272/ajay-managaon) suggested (but didn't nail the answer), this is what I believe is the answer:

#### A JWT Public Key ?

The JWT requires a `Public Key` to *help* validate it. There's some *other* validation steps also, but the `Public Key` is (excuse the pun) the key to kicking off this validation step.

Which means 2 things:

1. We can provide *a url* to where the public key can be found

or

2. We can provide the public key *directly*. (aka. it's hardcoded in some config settings or a file that is found next to the web api code, etc)

#### 1. We don't have the actual Public Key

So if we don't really know the `public key` OR the `public key` changes (aka. "rotates" often) .. then we should provide a URL to where this `public key` can be found.

Therefore we *should have* the code: `x.Authority = "https://some-issuer.com/";` so the validation step knows where to grab this `public key` from.

#### 2. We have the actual Public Key value

So we know the value of the `public key` and it's in a file or hardcoded somewhere. As such, we should *not* try and go to some external URL to download the `public key`.

Therefore, we *should not* have `x.Authority = "...";` in the code above.

#### Now to answer your questions

With your sample above, you do NOT have the `public key` anywhere at all. This means you need to grab it.

Which means you need to follow option 1 => "we don't have the actual public key".

Now looking at your code, the first chunk `Failing Settings` is failing because:

- ❌ You have not specified a URL to grab the `public key`. Aka. there is no `x.Authority` value set.
- ❌ You have not specified the actual `public key` to use. Aka. there is no `IssuerSigningKey` value set, as part of the `TokenValidationParameters` property.

As such -> it has no `public key` so it cannot do any validation.

Next, looking at your second piece of code, it has:

- ✅ `x.Authority = "https://blah...";` Nice! This is telling the validation code to grab the `public key` from that url.

Finally ... this question you've asked:

> I thought that ValidIssuer = "some-issuer" is the exact equiv to x.Authority ??

Nae - as Ajay mentioned (from the link he provided), it (`ValidIssuer`) must only check the `iss` value in the JWT. While `x.Authority` grabs the `public key` -and- checks the `iss` field in the JWT.

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly mentions, "The signature key was not found". Any JWT token you create needs to be signed with a key, which is usually kept as a secret or in appsettings.json file for testing purposes.

Add a key in appsettings.json file as below:

```
"JwtTokenKey": "JWT SECURITY SIGNATURE KEY" (value can be any strong key).
```

Add below in the Configure Services method:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JwtTokenKey"])),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true
                };
        });
```

You can set ValidateIssuer and ValidateAudience to false if you don't want to validate them.

Also make sure to add, `app.UseAuthentication()` middleware above `app.UseAuthorization()`

Editing the answer to answer the question:

`Authority` is the address of the token-issuing authentication server. The JWT bearer authentication middleware will use this URI to find and retrieve the public key that can be used to validate the token’s signature. It will also confirm that the iss parameter in the token matches this URI.

The Authority property should not be set on the JwtBearerOptions. If it’s set, the middleware assumes that it can go to that URI to get token validation information. In this scenario, the authority URI may not be available.

A new property (TokenValidationParameters) must be set on the JwtBearerOptions. This object allows the caller to specify more advanced options for how JWT tokens will be validated.

Here is the link which explains it in brief:

[Authority in JWT](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/#:%7E:text=Authority%20is%20the%20address%20of,to%20validate%20the%20token%27s%20signature.)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I don't think that is actually helping answer _my question_. I have it working _without a signing key_. What I wish to know is why the 2nd code works and the first one doesn't? The working one doesn't have the signing key.